# Javascript constant movement when hitting a key and then hitting shift

Tags: javascript, html

So currently I have a little script that moves my character up, down, left or right.

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    if (!(e.key == 'w' || e.key == 'a' || e.key == 's' || e.key == 'd' || e.shiftKey)) return;
    keys[e.key] = true;
})
window.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
    if (!(e.key == 'w' || e.key == 'a' || e.key == 's' || e.key == 'd' || e.shiftKey)) return;
    keys[e.key] = false;
})


function movement() {
    if (keys['w']){
        y -= speed;
    }
    if (keys['s']){
        y += speed;
    }
    if (keys['d']){
        x += speed;
    }
    if (keys['a']){
        x -= speed;
    }
    char.style.top = y + 'px';
    char.style.left = x + 'px';
}

setInterval(movement, 10)
```

Essentially all this does, is that once i hit a key down it adds it to the list as a bool, and ever 10 ms if a certain key is down I move in that direction. The problem is that if i'm hitting a key for example 's' to move down and while im holding the key down I hit the shift key, my character just continues to move in that direction even after I let go of the keys.

Comment: Maybe instead of booleans, store the current walltime (in ms or us) ? then your movement function can just check if the value in `keys` is `<= 10ms` compared to the current moment

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you continue to move is that in your `keyup` event listener, you use `e.shiftKey` in the conditional.

[e.shiftKey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/shiftKey) returns `true` if the shift key is pressed, otherwise false. Since this is a `keyup` event, there is no key pressed, meaning `e.shiftKey` will be false and you will `return` before setting a key to `false`.

However, you do have access to the name of the key in `e.key` so you can change your conditional to check for the name as you do with the other keys.

```
if (!(e.key === 'w' || e.key === 'a' || e.key === 's' || e.key === 'd' || e.key === 'Shift'))
```

A cleaner approach, to avoid repetition could be to add the allowed keys to an array, then check that `e.key` is in that list:

```js
const keys = {
  w: false,
  a: false,
  s: false,
  d: false,
  Shift: false,
}

const allowedKeys = ['w', 'a', 's', 'd', 'Shift']

window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    if (allowedKeys.indexOf(e.key) === -1) {
      return
    }
    keys[e.key] = true;
    console.log(keys)
})
window.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
    if (allowedKeys.indexOf(e.key) === -1) { // -1 = not found
      return
    }
    
    keys[e.key] = false;
    console.log(keys)
})
```